# Why exclusive-or does not include $\wedge \sim (p \wedge q)$?

Tags: analysis, logic

So we know that exclusive-or means "one or the other but not both" In logically equivalence, we can state it as $p\bigoplus q \equiv (p \wedge \sim q )\vee (\sim p \wedge q )$. I am just confusing about why it does not include "$\wedge \sim (p \wedge q)$ part following with the explanation "one or the other" and "but not both"?

Answer (score 0):

If $p \wedge q$, then $p$ and $q$ both hold true, so $\sim p$ and $\sim q$ both holds false. Thus, $p \wedge \sim q$ is false and $\sim p \wedge q$ is false, meaning $(p \wedge \sim q) \vee (\sim p \wedge q)$ is also false. Thus, $p \wedge q \implies \sim (p \bigoplus q)$ and by contrapositives, this means $p \bigoplus q \implies \sim (p \wedge q)$, so there is no need to include $\sim (p \wedge q)$ in the definition of $\bigoplus$ as that is implied by the definition already.

To make this more clear, let's make a truth table where $p$ and $q$ change and we look at the result of $\bigoplus$ and $\wedge$:

$p$ is false, $q$ is false $\rightarrow$ $p \bigoplus q$ is false, $p \wedge q$ is false

$p$ is true, $q$ is false $\rightarrow$ $p \bigoplus q$ is true, $p \wedge q$ is false

$p$ is false, $q$ is true $\rightarrow$ $p \bigoplus q$ is true, $p \wedge q$ is false

$p$ is true, $q$ is true $\rightarrow$ $p \bigoplus q$ is false, $p \wedge q$ is true

As you can see, $p \bigoplus q$ and $p \wedge q$ are never true at the same time. This shows us that if we added $\sim (p \wedge q)$ to the definition of $\bigoplus$, it would just be redundant since there is no case where $p \bigoplus q$ will be true when $p \wedge q$ is true.