# Equivalence of the exclusive disjunction while only using conjunction and negation

Tags: logic

So I have tried out multiple truth tables and finally came to the conclusion that
~(p^~q)^~(~p^q) is logically equivalent to p xor q.

However, the assignment says "define the exclusive disjunction". I'm not quite sure how to define this?

Comment: Not correct; your formula is equiv to $p \leftrightarrow q$.

Comment: Exclusive disjunction can be expressed in terms of the logical conjunction, the disjunction  and the negation as $(p\lor q)\land\neg(p\land q)$.

Comment: See the [Truth table for XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Truth_table).

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636587/why-exclusive-or-does-not-include-wedge-sim-p-wedge-q).

Comment: Sorry, I made an error. The forumule that I had was ~(~(p^~q)^~(~p^q)). I had to define it in terms of ^ and ~.

Comment: Correct : $\lnot [\lnot (\lnot p \land q) \land \lnot (p \land \lnot q)]$

Comment: Oh thank you. I checked out the post, but still find it quite hard to give a definition. How should I approach this? I can mention the given formula, but how can this be defined?

Answer (score 1):

> Oh thank you. I checked out the post, but still find it quite hard to give a definition. How should I approach this? I can mention the given formula, but how can this be defined?

Exclusive Disjunction ("the disjunction excluding the conjunction") may be defined as "at least one term is true but *not both* are true", or that "one term is true but the other is not."

Thus you begin with either a CNF or DNF form, and then you apply deMorgan's Laws until disjunctions no longer appear.

$$\begin{array}{l|l}{\begin{split}p\oplus q&\equiv(p\vee q)\wedge\neg(p\wedge q)\\&\equiv \neg(\neg p\wedge\neg q)\wedge\neg(p\wedge q)\end{split}}\qquad&\qquad{\begin{split}p\oplus q&\equiv(p\wedge\neg q)\vee(\neg p\wedge q)\\&\equiv \neg(\neg(p\wedge\neg q)\wedge\neg(\neg p\wedge q))\end{split}}\end{array}$$